# ¿Cómo obtener información de las transacciones realizadas desde la API de PayPal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Desarrollo una aplicación en Asp.Net MVC  y  voy a utilizar  PayPal para que los clientes se suscriban y realicen pagos de los productos que se ofertan, utilizo botones que redireccionan a los clientes a la pagina de Paypal allí se logean  y realizan sus transacciones…hasta aquí todo bien.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener información de las transacciones  realizadas? , necesitó obtener información acerca de una transacción específica o una lista de transacciones entre dos fechas, ¿Esto se puede hacer?

Ya he construido un método que obtiene el token de Acceso y otro para recibir  notificaciones (WebHook) donde puedo recibir  información cuando ocurren eventos, pero la verdad no estoy muy claro en el funcionamiento de la Api en cuanto a mi duda.

Obtener token:

```
  public async Task<RespuestaPaypalToken> GetTokenPaypal()
    {
        string respuesta = string.Empty;
        RespuestaPaypalToken R = new RespuestaPaypalToken();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EngineData.ClientId + ":" + EngineData.KeySecret);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            Uri url = new Uri(EngineData.EndPointTokenPaypal, UriKind.Absolute);
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(EngineData.Grant_Type, EngineData.Client_Credentials));
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                R = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RespuestaPaypalToken>(respuesta);
            }
        }
        return R;
    }
```

Recibir Notificaciones (WebHook):

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public void WebHookPay()
        {
            string cadena = string.Empty;
            if (Request.RequestType.Equals("POST"))
            {
                var stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
                stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                cadena = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Botones HTML

```
 <div id="comprarAhora" class="divIzquierda">
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXQPJDJJZLRBE">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma rápida y segura de pagar en Internet.">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="subcripcion" class="divDerecha">
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6D8R9ZT8S939L">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma rápida y segura de pagar en Internet.">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div id="cancelarSubcripcion" align="center">
    <A HREF="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=J54EPFNPQC8WG">
        <IMG SRC="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif" BORDER="0">
    </A>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has revisado algo de la documentación que ofrece el mismo Paypal?